Why do I get a ValueError whenever there is any special character?
I'm trying to add typed in numbers to a list.
box = [int(x) for x in input("Type numbers here: ").split()]

box.sort(reverse=False)

print(box)

This code gets ValueError whenever there is any special character. Meaning you need to type numbers with spaces between them and if there is a comma it doesn't work. It's not allowing float numbers. I changed type to float to allow numbers such as 2,5 and experimented with re.sub() but it doesn't work.

Python floating-point format uses . for the decimal point, not ,, unless you use the locale module to do the conversion.

int() wouldn't generate floating point numbers anyway, so what output were you expecting? Can you show how you tried re.sub?

If you really wanna use commas and not dots for floating-points do below
box = [float(x.replace(',','.')) for x in input("Type numbers here: ").split()]

box.sort(reverse=False)

print(box)

where a replace function changes , to .

You know that the input is considered as string even if we type numbers. And that is why you are converting this into int to create a list(like box = [int(x) for x in input("Type numbers here: ").split()]).
So the characters which can't be converted into integers will naturally raise value error. If at all you want to give mixed types of data in your code, You have to pre-process your input in your coding according to your requirement. For example, if you need some of the special characters to use in later steps, you can create another list with containing special characters; And one list containing numbers.
Few examples:
If the input is numbers separated by commas,
numbers = input("Type numbers here: ")
numbers = numbers.split(',')
numbers = [int(x) for x in numbers]

If you want to use float numbers separated by space, Rest of the characters to use in later stage
numbers = input("Type numbers here: ")
numbers = numbers.split(' ')
ints = [float(x) for x in numbers if x.replace('.','').isdigit()]
char = [x for x in numbers if not x.replace('.','').isdigit()]

and so on.
